# long long int vs. long int vs. int64_t in C++

Tags: c++, gcc, cstdint

I experienced some odd behavior while using C++ type traits and have narrowed my problem down to this quirky little problem for which I will give a ton of explanation since I do not want to leave anything open for misinterpretation.

Say you have a program like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

template <typename T>
bool is_int64() { return false; }

template <>
bool is_int64<int64_t>() { return true; }

int main()
{
 std::cout << "int:\t" << is_int64<int>() << std::endl;
 std::cout << "int64_t:\t" << is_int64<int64_t>() << std::endl;
 std::cout << "long int:\t" << is_int64<long int>() << std::endl;
 std::cout << "long long int:\t" << is_int64<long long int>() << std::endl;

 return 0;
}
```

In both 32-bit compile with GCC (and with 32- and 64-bit MSVC), the output of the program will be:

```
int:           0
int64_t:       1
long int:      0
long long int: 1
```

However, the program resulting from a 64-bit GCC compile will output:

```
int:           0
int64_t:       1
long int:      1
long long int: 0
```

This is curious, since `long long int` is a signed 64-bit integer and is, for all intents and purposes, identical to the `long int` and `int64_t` types, so logically, `int64_t`, `long int` and `long long int` would be equivalent types - the assembly generated when using these types is identical.  One look at `stdint.h` tells me why:

```
# if __WORDSIZE == 64
typedef long int  int64_t;
# else
__extension__
typedef long long int  int64_t;
# endif
```

In a 64-bit compile, `int64_t` is `long int`, not a `long long int` (obviously).

The fix for this situation is pretty easy:

```
#if defined(__GNUC__) && (__WORDSIZE == 64)
template <>
bool is_int64<long long int>() { return true; }
#endif
```

But this is horribly hackish and does not scale well (actual functions of substance, `uint64_t`, etc).  **So my question is:** Is there a way to tell the compiler that a `long long int` is the also a `int64_t`, just like `long int` is?

---

My initial thoughts are that this is not possible, due to the way C/C++ type definitions work.  There is not a way to specify type equivalence of the basic data types to the compiler, since that is the compiler's job (and allowing that could break a lot of things) and `typedef` only goes one way.

I'm also not too concerned with getting an answer here, since this is a super-duper edge case that I do not suspect anyone will ever care about when the examples are not horribly contrived (does that mean this should be community wiki?).

---

**Append**: The reason why I'm using partial template specialization instead of an easier example like:

```
void go(int64_t) { }

int main()
{
    long long int x = 2;
    go(x);
    return 0;
}
```

is that said example will still compile, since `long long int` is implicitly convertible to an `int64_t`.

---

**Append**: The only answer so far assumes that I want to know if a type is 64-bits.  I did not want to mislead people into thinking that I care about that and probably should have provided more examples of where this problem manifests itself.

```
template <typename T>
struct some_type_trait : boost::false_type { };

template <>
struct some_type_trait<int64_t> : boost::true_type { };
```

In this example, `some_type_trait<long int>` will be a `boost::true_type`, but `some_type_trait<long long int>` will not be.  While this makes sense in C++'s idea of types, it is not desirable.

Another example is using a qualifier like `same_type` (which is pretty common to use in C++0x Concepts):

```
template <typename T>
void same_type(T, T) { }

void foo()
{
    long int x;
    long long int y;
    same_type(x, y);
}
```

That example fails to compile, since C++ (correctly) sees that the types are different.  g++ will fail to compile with an error like: no matching function call `same_type(long int&, long long int&)`.

I would like to stress that I understand *why* this is happening, but I am looking for a workaround that does not force me to repeat code all over the place.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does your sample program give the same results for the `sizeof` each type? Perhaps the compiler is treating the size of `long long int` differently.

Comment: Have you compiled with C++0x enabled? C++03 doesn't have `<cstdint>`, so maybe the fact it has to say "this is an extension" (which it is) is foobaring it.

Comment: Yes, I should have probably specified that I'm using `--std=c++0x` .  And yes, `sizeof(long long int) == sizeof(long int) == sizeof(int64_t) == 8`.

Comment: Nobody mentioned this yet, but in case it was overlooked: `long` and `long long` are distinct types (even if they have the same size & representation).  `int64_t` is always an alias for another existing type (despite its name, `typedef` doesn't create new types, it just gives an alias to one that exists already)

Comment: One important statement is missing from the answers/comments, which helped me when this quirk hit me: *Never use fixed-size types for reliably specializing templates. Always use basic types and cover all possible cases* (even if you use fixed-size types to instantiate those templates). *All possible cases* means: if you need to instantiate with `int16_t`, then specialize with `short` and `int` and you'll be covered. (and with `signed char` if you're feeling adventurous)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You don't need to go to 64-bit to see something like this. Consider `int32_t` on common 32-bit platforms. It might be `typedef`'ed as `int` or as a `long`, but obviously only one of the two at a time. `int` and `long` are of course distinct types.

It's not hard to see that there is no workaround which makes `int == int32_t == long` on 32-bit systems. For the same reason, there's no way to make `long == int64_t == long long` on 64-bit systems.

If you could, the possible consequences would be rather painful for code that overloaded `foo(int)`, `foo(long)` and `foo(long long)` - suddenly they'd have two definitions for the same overload?!

The correct solution is that your template code usually should not be relying on a precise type, but on the properties of that type. The whole `same_type` logic could still be OK for specific cases:

```
long foo(long x);
std::tr1::disable_if(same_type(int64_t, long), int64_t)::type foo(int64_t);
```

I.e., the overload `foo(int64_t)` is not defined when it's *exactly* the same as `foo(long)`.

[edit]
With C++11, we now have a standard way to write this:

```
long foo(long x);
std::enable_if<!std::is_same<int64_t, long>::value, int64_t>::type foo(int64_t);
```

[edit]
Or C++20

```
long foo(long x);
int64_t foo(int64_t) requires (!std::is_same_v<int64_t, long>);
```

Comment: Sad news is, e.g. on 64bit MSVC19 (2017) `sizeof()` `long` and `int` is identical, but `std::is_same<long, int>::value` returns `false`. Same weirdness on AppleClang 9.1 on OSX HighSierra.

Comment: @Ax3l: That's not weird. Virtually every compiler since ISO C 90 has at least one such pair.

Comment: That's true, they are distinct types.

Answer (score 7):

Do you want to know if a type is the same type as int64_t or do you want to know if something is 64 bits? Based on your proposed solution, I think you're asking about the latter. In that case, I would do something like

```
template<typename T>
bool is_64bits() { return sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT == 64; } // or >= 64
```

Comment: Aren't you missing a `return` and a semicolon?

Comment: Not what I'm looking for at all.  The example was provided to show a way for the error to manifest itself, not as an actual requirement.

Comment: Still, you should be using `sizeof` for this.

Comment: No, I shouldn't.  `template <T> struct has_trivial_destructor : boost::false_type { }; template <> struct has_trivial_destructor<int64_t> : boost::true_type { };`  Now `has_trivial_destructor<long long int>` will be erroneously be a `boost::false_type`. That is an example of this problem manifesting itself that has nothing to do with variable size.

Comment: long long int and long int are not the same type whether or not they happen to be the same size. The behavior is not erroneous. That's just C++.

Comment: While C++ sees them as different types, GCC's code generator treats them in the exact same way.  I mean erroneous in the context usage, not in the context of the language.  This brings me to my original question, which is: What is a good way to resolve this issue?  I ask because I do not think there is one.

Comment: What issue? Are you trying to determine how the code generator behaves from a source code level? Or do you just not want to type `template <> struct trait<long long int> { ... }` because you expect `template <> struct trait<int64_t> { ... }` to "cover" it? It's entirely possible for a compiler to have a `long long int` that is bigger than 64bits. This is the same "problem" you'd have with `int32_t` and `int` and `long int` on some compilers. `int64_t` isn't all possible 64 bit signed numeric builtin types, it is one of those built in types that satisfies the condition of being 64bits.

Comment: I know.  The underlying question (which I'm having a difficult time expressing) is really a question of the C++ type system.  `int64_t` is just one example of this.  There are many types which, at code generation time, are the *exact same* (like `long int` and `long long int` in 64-bit GCC), yet at C++ time, they are not recognized as the same type.  This seems to be a fundamental limitation of C++'s type system -- how does one get around it in a clean(/not as ugly) way?

Comment: I don't think I'd call this a limitation. If you could get around it, it would be a violation of the principle of nominal type equality present in C++. For example, if specializing on `long int` counted as a specialization on `long long int`, then consider `struct A { int a; };` and `struct B { int a; };` Should specializing on A also apply to B? They will generate the same code after all. There _are_ languages that work like this, C++ just isn't one of them.

Comment: Then would it be fair to say that this is a limitation of nominal typing?

Comment: Well it's intrisic to the whole idea, in C++ types are identified by their names. This also makes useful things like forward declaration pimpl and pointers type safe. In most C++ impls string* and int* are the same size for instance. A language with structural (sub)typing would have different limitations and tradeoffs. Lots of C++ template programming relies on tags (empty structs) which would stop working. This is one of those cake and eating it too things.

Comment: It's not a limitation of nominal typing.  It's a limitation of *meaningless* nominal typing.  In the old days, the de facto standard was `short` = 16 bits, `long` = 32 bits, and `int` = native size.  In these days of 64-bit, `int` and `long` don't *mean* anything anymore.

Comment: @dan04: They're no more or less meaningful than they ever were.  `short` is *at least* 16 bits, `int` is at least 16 bits, and `long` is at least 32 bits, with (sloppy notation follows) short <= int <= long.  The "old days" you refer to never existed; there have always been variations within the restrictions imposed by the language.  The "All the world's an x86" fallacy is just as dangerous as the older "All the world's a VAX fallacy.

Answer (score 4):

> So my question is: Is there a way to tell the compiler that a long long int is the also a int64_t, just like long int is?

This is a good question or problem, but I suspect the answer is NO.

Also, a `long int` may not be a `long long int`.

---

> ```
> # if __WORDSIZE == 64
> typedef long int  int64_t;
> # else
> __extension__
> typedef long long int  int64_t;
> # endif
> ```

I believe this is libc. I suspect you want to go deeper.

> In both 32-bit compile with GCC (and with 32- and 64-bit MSVC), the
>   output of the program will be:
>
> ```
> int:           0
> int64_t:       1
> long int:      0
> long long int: 1
> ```

32-bit Linux uses the ILP32 data model. Integers, longs and pointers are 32-bit. The 64-bit type is a `long long`.

Microsoft documents the ranges at [Data Type Ranges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx). The say the `long long` is equivalent to `__int64`.

> However, the program resulting from a 64-bit GCC compile will output:
>
> ```
> int:           0
> int64_t:       1
> long int:      1
> long long int: 0
> ```

64-bit Linux uses the `LP64` data model. Longs are 64-bit and `long long` are 64-bit. As with 32-bit, Microsoft documents the ranges at [Data Type Ranges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx) and long long is still `__int64`.

There's a `ILP64` data model where everything is 64-bit. You have to do some extra work to get a definition for your `word32` type. Also see papers like [64-Bit Programming Models: Why LP64?](http://www.unix.org/version2/whatsnew/lp64_wp.html)

---

> But this is horribly hackish and does not scale well (actual functions of substance, uint64_t, etc)...

Yeah, it gets even better. GCC mixes and matches declarations that are supposed to take 64 bit types, so its easy to get into trouble even though you follow a particular data model. For example, the following causes a compile error and tells you to use `-fpermissive`:

```
#if __LP64__
typedef unsigned long word64;
#else
typedef unsigned long long word64;
#endif

// intel definition of rdrand64_step (http://software.intel.com/en-us/node/523864)
// extern int _rdrand64_step(unsigned __int64 *random_val);

// Try it:
word64 val;
int res = rdrand64_step(&val);
```

It results in:

```
error: invalid conversion from `word64* {aka long unsigned int*}' to `long long unsigned int*'
```

So, ignore `LP64` and change it to:

```
typedef unsigned long long word64;
```

Then, wander over to a 64-bit ARM IoT gadget that defines `LP64` and use NEON:

```
error: invalid conversion from `word64* {aka long long unsigned int*}' to `uint64_t*'
```